# How to write function series in Mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

How do  I write the function given below as a mathematical function:

$\Sigma^{8}_{i=1}\Sigma^{8}_{j=1}c_{ij}\lambda_i \otimes\lambda_j$

I have the values of $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$.They are 3x3 matrices.

Comment: why are you using cross product between two matrices?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming $\otimes$ means normal matrix multiplication. In that case

```
n=8;
mat=Table[ResourceFunction["RandomMatrix"][Integer,{0,10},{3,3}],{n}];
sum=Sum[Sum[c[i,j]* (mat[[i]].mat[[j]]),{j,1,n}],{i,1,n}];
```

If normal matrix product is not what you meant, then try instead tensor product

```
Sum[Sum[c[i, j]*KroneckerProduct[mat[[i]], mat[[j]]], {j, 1, n}],{i, 1, 8}];
```

Or may be you meant

```
Sum[Sum[c[i,j]* TensorProduct[mat[[i]],mat[[j]]],{j,1,n}],{i,1,8}];
```

You can try them and see which one is what you had in mind.

You really should make it clear what $\otimes$ means here.

Comment: $\otimes$ means tensor product between matrices